# mojoportal - do i need the source code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mojoportal

I just inherited a site built on the mojoPortal CMS but we don't have the source code. Do I need it to continue developing the site? It seems like I do, but I'm wondering if there are any workarounds (something stored in the db?) that I'm unaware of considering I'm pretty new to mojoPortal.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't do programming work on a site without the source code.

Comment: If you're going to modify the core and stock modules of mojoportal you will need the source code. And you will need the source code of third-part modules if you''re going to modify only them. If you plan to develop only your own modules, I think you can do without the souce code.

Comment: Thanks @mishau, I was guessing that was the case. I'm curious if I can add modules though, considering there are no code-behind files (aspx.cs) included with the release build of mojoPortal. I added some very benign JavaScript to a single .aspx page and the entire site crashed, so I'm very hesitant to do anything without the source! We may just have to start over.

Comment: I think you shoulds study this first: [adding-custom-javascript](http://www.mojoportal.com/adding-custom-javascript.aspx), or this may be [creatingskins](http://www.mojoportal.com/creatingskins.aspx). Also examine profoundly the architecture of the egnine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark B, you can download the mojoPortal source code from every version since 2.2.7.6 [here](http://mojoportal.codeplex.com/releases/view/81157), see the "Other Downloads" box.

To find out your current version, go to the Administration->System Information menu in your site, it looks like this:

[image: mojoPortal Version Information]